# How can I set up a time resource in concourse for every hour at 00 minutes?

Tags: concourse

I can't find it in the dock(https://concourse-ci.org /) this setting.
There is a type:

```
source:
    interval: 1h # 
    location: Europe/Moscow
```

But the problem with this setup is that it starts every hour, and the hour is counted from the moment the previous cycle is completed (I think so, because the schedule is gradually shifting forward, which is generally fast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the `time` resource doesn't implement precision.

Use the `cron` resource instead: https://github.com/pivotal-cf-experimental/cron-resource

```
---
resource_types:
- name: cron-resource
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: cftoolsmiths/cron-resource

resources:
  - name: 00-trigger
    type: cron-resource
    source:
      expression: "0 * * * *"
      location: "Europe/Moscow"
```